High dosage of herbicide application and possible almond tree damage
Recently I have started working in a massive orchard. But apparently, the management is not that great. Following the herbicide applications, I noticed that they are mixing glyphosate and dicamba. However, reading the labels I noticed that the dicamba is being used about 5 times the recommended upper level and glyphosate above the upper limits. Moreover, they are not considering the strip application and broadband application differences. Where applying to less than half of the total area would mean 2 times higher rates of glyphosate and 10 times of dicamba is being applied.
In walnut trees still there is no visible damage, but, in almond trees you can see bunch of trees like the one on the photo. I would like to ask, if there is any reasonable justification possible for this levels of herbicide use and if can conclude this damages are actually from herbicide rather than a virus?
thank you everyone!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no photo. In any case: there is no need to exceed recommended doses: same effect, higher costs. Plus residuals may cause longer problems (and on neighbourhood, water management system). Such behaviour is more a social problem: to show I know things, I'm allowed to do it, I'm better. Damage: it depends *how they did it". For sure there is higher risk, e.g. if trunk has damages or low branches). If you cannot identify common viruses (for your region), there is just one obvious reason

A higher than recommended concentration of dicamba will result in higher volatility, especially in warm weather. This means that some of the dicamba will essentially become air-borne and can definitely damage tree leaves (happened in my city last year). The good news is that the dicamba did not kill the oaks, birches, and locusts that it affected - they looked like death last year, but all have come back this year, although the more mature trees have suffered permanent losses of lower limbs. The evidence of harbicide damage would be extremely curled leaves.
